# Pass associative arrays in call_user_func_array(...)

Tags: php, templating

I'm building a templating system and I'm running in to an issue with calling functions on the fly.

When I try the following:

```
$args = array(
    4,
    'test' => 'hello',
    'hi'
);
```

You know.. some numerical elements some associative elements,

```
call_user_func_array($function, $args);
```

converts the array to something like this:

```
$args = array(
    4,
    'hello',
    'hi'
);
```

Is there any way around this other than passing an array like this:

```
$args = array(
    4,
    array('test' => 'hello'),
    'hi'
);
```

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: Can you show what is being done with `$args` in `$function`?

Comment: $function is just a string like 'to_lowercase' or something..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's nowhere for the array keys to go because:

```
call_user_func_array($function, $args);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
$function(4, 'hello', 'hi');
```

You could use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call_user_func) instead:

```
call_user_func($function, $args);
```

then given a function with one argument, you can get the associative array:

```
function func($args) {
//    $args is complete associative array
}
```

Note that `call_user_func()` can also take more than one argument - each will be passed to the called function as an argument.

Comment: Oh really? I feel silly- I know I tried call_user_func() before deciding on call_user_func_array(), I guess my requirements must have changed. If I do func_get_args($args) will it return an array of the associative array?

Comment: yeah, func_get_args() == array($args) in the above example